# How to compare two regex matches?

Tags: c#, regex

I'm making a software for TV series and I want to verify that two regex matches have the same meaning in a foreach loop (eg. S03E01 == 03x01).

Here's the code I have:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"S?\d{1,2}[x|e]?\d{1,2}", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
foreach (string file in path) {
    if (regex.IsMatch(file)) {
                //something
    }
}
```

how do I do that?

Comment: @almasshaikh see  `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` in his code..

Comment: Is it possible that you have S3E1 and 03x01 to compare? (and it should return true for you)

Comment: I have never seen S3E1, but 03x01 yes

Comment: What I meant was that for example `03` and `3` when comparing strings is different, but `03` and `3` numerically are the same. But oh well, codemonkey already provided for that situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transform the filename to one format and keep them in a collection to match them:

```
        Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string,string>();

        Regex regex = new Regex(@"S?(\d{1,2})[x|e]?(\d{1,2})", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        foreach (string file in path)
        {
            var match = regex.Match(file);
            if (match.Success)
            {
                string key = "S" + match.Groups[1].Value.PadLeft(2, '0') + "E" + match.Groups[2].Value.PadLeft(2, '0');
                if (dict.ContainsKey(key))
                {
                    // .. already in there
                }
                else
                {
                    dict[key] = file;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Edited the response to compensate for matching S1E10 and S01E10